# Solving this quadratic equation by completing the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

**$-\frac{2}{3}x^{2} - x +2 = 0$**

Here's what I did:
[image]

However, the textbook answer is **$x = -2.6, x = 1.1$**. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What just happened on the second line? There seems to be an extra $(3/2-1/2)^2$ there which wasn't before, and has no good reason to be there anyway..

Comment: @dxiv in order to complete the square, i had to divide b by 2 then square it... since it's a fraction, i multiplied by it's reciprocal

Comment: Then but you just added an unjustified $1$ in the process. You should also add $-1$ in the parenthesis.

Comment: @JennyB If you add something to one side of the equation, then you must either subtract it back, or add it to the other side as well, otherwise you are changing the equation to a different one. Besides, that's not the right thing to add in order to complete the square. Think at it as $x^2 + 2 \cdot \dfrac{3}{4}x + \color{red}{?} = \left(x+\color{red}{??}\right)^2$ instead.

Comment: @Jenny B Your mistake was between lines 3 and 4 . 3/2 is not the square root of 9/16.

Comment: @SteveB but while squaring, we also multiply the term by $2$, so it becomes $2 \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @ArsenBerk It would become that if the second term in the binomial were a $\frac{3}{4}$ Unfortunately, on Jenny's paper, is is a $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Line two you add $\frac 32\frac12$ out of nowhere without balancing it by either adding it also to the other side or by subtracting it on the outside of the parenthesis.  On line three you add $\frac 38$ from no where for no reason that I can see.

Comment: While your work is easy to read, images cannot be searched.  You should typeset your work, which you could to in this case by using [aligned equations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong in this step:

$-\cfrac{2}{3}\biggl(x^2+\cfrac{3}{2}x+\cfrac{9}{16}\biggr)+2+\cfrac{3}{8}=0$

$-\cfrac{2}{3}\biggl(x^2+\cfrac{3}{2}\biggr)^2+\cfrac{19}{8}=0$  $\leftarrow$ Here

The actual result of that is:

$-\cfrac{2}{3}\biggl(x^2+\cfrac{3}{4}\biggr)^2+\cfrac{19}{8}=0$

Comment: There should not be an addition sign between the $-2/3$ and the term in parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

$$-\frac{2}{3}\bigg(x^2+\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{9}{16} \bigg)+\frac{19}{8}$$
is the equivalent of this expression in a square form. Here notice that constant term should be equal to $2$, therefore we add $\dfrac{19}{8}$ in order to have $-\dfrac{2}{3} \cdot \dfrac{9}{16} + \dfrac{19}{8} = 2$.

For the rest of the question, your logic is completely correct so I leave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
-\frac{2}{3}x^2 - x + 2 & = 0\\
-\frac{2}{3}\left(x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x\right) + 2 & = 0\\
-\frac{2}{3}\left[x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right] \color{red}{- \left[-\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right]} + 2 & = 0 \tag{1}\\
-\frac{2}{3}\left(x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{9}{16}\right) + \frac{3}{8} + 2 & = 0\\
-\frac{2}{3}\left(x + \color{red}{\frac{3}{4}}\right)^2 + \frac{19}{8} & = 0 \tag{2}\\
-\frac{2}{3}\left(x + \frac{3}{4}\right)^2 & = -\frac{19}{8}\\
\left(x + \frac{3}{4}\right)^2 & = \frac{57}{16}\\
\left|x + \frac{3}{4}\right| & = \sqrt{\frac{57}{16}}\\
x + \frac{3}{4} & = \pm \frac{\sqrt{57}}{4} \tag{3}\\
x & = -\frac{3}{4} \pm \frac{\sqrt{57}}{4}\\
x & = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{57}}{4}
\end{align*}

(1):  If you add a term to one side of the equation, you must either add it to the other side of the equation or subtract it from the same side of the equation to balance the equation.  You omitted the term in red.

(2):  Note that 
$$\frac{9}{16} = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$$
You made the mistake of treating $9/16$ as the square of $3/2$.

(3):  Since $16$ is a perfect square, you do not need to rationalize the denominator in this step.  What you did was correct, but introducing extra steps introduces extra opportunities to make an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment.

Make your life easy by writing

$$-\frac23x^2-x+2=0\iff x^2+\frac32x-3=0.$$

Then

$$\left(x+\frac34\right)^2-\left(\frac34\right)^2-3=0,$$

$$\left(x+\frac34\right)^2=\frac{57}{16},$$

$$x+\frac34=\pm\frac{\sqrt{57}}4.$$